# Testing windows installers

Tags: windows, testing, user-interface, installation

I work at a software company,
And we have a product for Windows OS that is installed using a custom installer.

We want to have an automated system that will run the installer on a daily basis, make sure that everything is installed and functional (application installed, appears in Add/Remove, shortcut created, registry keys created, browser addons installed, etc)
I also want to test the functionality of the app by using a GUI macro of some sort.

Is there anything like what i'm looking for?

Comment: An old but related post, for info if nothing else http://stackoverflow.com/q/1100040/2065121

Comment: I have seen this post already, but i am looking for something more mature then scripting.

Comment: Ok, I just highlighted it in case - I don't know of anything but this would also be very useful for us too, so I'm keeping an eye on your question!

Comment: @DeaglinG Are you trying to test the application that has been installed or the installer UI?  Also are you looking for a record and playback tool of some sort or are you willing to write some code to do it?

Comment: I'm trying to test the installer itself first. I don't mind writing code for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up using TestComplete 9 from SmartBear: https://smartbear.com

Its doing exactly what we need, and it has many advanced features like connecting to remote virtual computers for parallel testing.